# Javascript Detect if Adobe Reader is installed

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat, browser-plugin

We have some PDF forms that don't display correctly in non-Adobe PDF readers (i.e. WebKit's built-in PDF reader **does not** properly display some proprietary Adobe things). We want to detect when users don't have *Adobe's* PDF Reader installed and give them a little warning, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it in 2014.

It seems [this script](https://gist.github.com/benkitzelman/6d4ead05b3d4b80518f3) worked in 2011. Basically it loops through `navigator.plugins` and looks for plugins with the name `Adobe Acrobat` or `Chrome PDF Viewer`.

```
 for(key in navigator.plugins) {
      var plugin = navigator.plugins[key];
      if(plugin.name == "Adobe Acrobat") return plugin;
 }
```

Flash forward to today, Adobe must have changed something, because I have Adobe Acrobat installed, but it doesn't seem to be in `navigator.plugins`! Where is it now and how do I detect it?

Comment: I've tested that script here and it works perfectly fine in both Firefox and Chrome. IE however doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Do you have an old version of `Adobe Reader`? It doesn't even show up in the list of plugins on my computer.

Comment: Ye. I'm working on it for IE. It seems like the script doesn't detect the IE browser. Oh and I've got Adobe Reader XI installed

Answer (score 12):

Ok I've updated the script and it's working perfectly fine in all browsers now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> New Document </title>
        <script>
        //
        // http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com
        // @author: Ben Kitzelman
        // @license: FreeBSD: (http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause) Do whatever you like with it
        // @updated: 03-03-2013
        //
        var getAcrobatInfo = function() {

            var getBrowserName = function() {
                return this.name = this.name || function() {
                    var userAgent = navigator ? navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() : "other";

                    if(userAgent.indexOf("chrome") > -1){
                        return "chrome";
                    } else if(userAgent.indexOf("safari") > -1){
                        return "safari";
                    } else if(userAgent.indexOf("msie") > -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > 0){
                        return "ie";
                    } else if(userAgent.indexOf("firefox") > -1){
                        return "firefox";
                    } else {
                        //return "ie";
                        return userAgent;
                    }
                }();
            };

            var getActiveXObject = function(name) {
                try { return new ActiveXObject(name); } catch(e) {}
            };

            var getNavigatorPlugin = function(name) {
                for(key in navigator.plugins) {
                    var plugin = navigator.plugins[key];
                    if(plugin.name == name) return plugin;
                }
            };

            var getPDFPlugin = function() {
                return this.plugin = this.plugin || function() {
                    if(getBrowserName() == 'ie') {
                        //
                        // load the activeX control
                        // AcroPDF.PDF is used by version 7 and later
                        // PDF.PdfCtrl is used by version 6 and earlier
                        return getActiveXObject('AcroPDF.PDF') || getActiveXObject('PDF.PdfCtrl');
                    } else {
                        return getNavigatorPlugin('Adobe Acrobat') || getNavigatorPlugin('Chrome PDF Viewer') || getNavigatorPlugin('WebKit built-in PDF');
                    }
                }();
            };

            var isAcrobatInstalled = function() {
                return !!getPDFPlugin();
            };

            var getAcrobatVersion = function() {
                try {
                    var plugin = getPDFPlugin();

                    if(getBrowserName() == 'ie') {
                        var versions = plugin.GetVersions().split(',');
                        var latest = versions[0].split('=');
                        return parseFloat(latest[1]);
                    }

                    if(plugin.version) return parseInt(plugin.version);
                    return plugin.name
                }
                catch(e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            //
            // The returned object
            //
            return {
                browser: getBrowserName(),
                acrobat: isAcrobatInstalled() ? 'installed' : false,
                acrobatVersion: getAcrobatVersion()
            };
        };

        var info = getAcrobatInfo();
        alert(info.browser+ " " + info.acrobat + " " + info.acrobatVersion);
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks--on the non-Explorer front, I discovered that while Adobe doesn't install Acrobat into Chrome, it does in Firefox, but the script wasn't detecting it because it was doing `if(plugin.name == name)`, but since the name is `Adobe Acrobat NPAPI Plug-In, Version 11.0.09`, that was coming up false. The line should probably be changed to `if(plugin.name.indexOf(name)>-1)`. I still don't know why the plugin isn't in Chrome though.

Comment: Well I've never done anything weird with my Chrome or Adobe Reader and the script above detects it just fine in Chrome. So I find it very strange that it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Ah, I thought it wasn't just me because everyone else in the office had the same result. We must have all done the same weird thing to Chrome!

Comment: Ghehe that'd be something xD But unfortunetely I can't fix what isn't broken here. IE unable to reproduce your problem. So I'm afraid you're on your own with that.