# Detect native or third-party PDF plugin in browser

Tags: javascript, html

We're writing a small tool to view generated PDFs from our site and have the browser open them.  The twist in our case is that we want the PDF to show in the browser 100% of the time. We do not want the browser to save the PDF to its downloads folder automatically (for HIPAA reasons).  (If the users download it themselves, that is fine.  The save being initiated by them is a very important distinction.)

I would like to find a solution that compromises between browser and the need for this extra.  My plan of attack is:

1. Detect native browser plugin, e.g. Google Chrome and Firefox.
2. If no native browser plugin is available, check for third-party plugins, e.g. for Adobe, or FoxIt.
3. If no third-party plugin is available, render with PDF.js or some other Javascript solution.

I am unsure how to go about step 1.  I've found a few hits for step 2, but I want to get step 1 working as that is the primary use case.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If the PDF is viewable in the browser by *any* mechanism, then by definition the browser will have downloaded the file.

Comment: I've edited the post. Sorry if it was not clear.  We (our CEO) wants the PDF to not be saved into the browser's downloads folder.  We are not concerned about the cache.  We want the PDF to display in the browser 100% of the time, even if no PDF plugin is installed.

Comment: the server application is coded in php, asp? if you render the file using  header('Content-type: application/pdf'); the file will be automatically view by the default browser pdf viewer

Comment: if you really think that HIPAA is a problem for the download folder but not the browser cache folder then you're really in trouble.  That just makes this a case of the XY Problem in good disguise.

Comment: @TotPeRo: It's for ASP.NET MVC. I think that even with the content-type set, the file will download if no pdf viewer plugin is installed right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want render the pdf file from the server programmatically you need to add mime type to header:

PhP example:

```
<?php
  $file = 'path/to/PDF/file.pdf';
  $filename = 'filename.pdf';
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  @readfile($file);
?>
```

C# example:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=something.pdf")
Return File(output, "application/pdf", "something.pdf")
```

Or if you want to detect the pdf viewer using JavaScript this can be help you: [Javascript Detect if Adobe Reader is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764842/javascript-detect-if-adobe-reader-is-installed)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.  If I'm able to find the Google and Firefox plugins with that, it will be enough for us.